# Signature error using std::getline() in C++

Tags: c++, stl

This is my code:

```
    std::string currentItem;
    char delimeter = '=';

    std::vector<std::string> afterSplit;
    for (int i =0; i<linesOfConfigFile.size(); i++)
    {
        const std::stringstream singleLine(linesOfConfigFile[i]);

        while(std::getline(singleLine, currentItem, delimeter))
            afterSplit.push_back(currentItem);
    }
```

I am getting error on the getline function call at the third last line. 
Compiler says:

`no matching function for call to getline(const std::stringstream&, std::string&, char&)'`

However, I cannot find what the issue is. The parameters are correct ?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::stringstream singleLine(linesOfConfigFile[i]);
```

not

```
const std::stringstream singleLine(linesOfConfigFile[i]);
```

Doesn't make much sense to declare a stream const since every read or write modifies the stream state.